# PHP str_replace not passing data

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract HTML code from a website.

First, I insert the HTML into a .txt file. Then, another page fopens the txt file while str_replacing selected regex.

I keep getting resource ID #4 on this below script.
I don't know why information is not passing through. I'm rusty.

I want to trim the selected data from the .txt file and insert it into another .txt file.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$fp = fopen('newfile2.txt', 'r');
echo '$fp is resource = ' . (is_resource($fp) ? 'true': 'false');

$re = '/(\n*.*+)+\1<tr>\n.*<td bgcolor=\"#ffffcc\">/'; 
$subst = "<tr><td>"; 

$result = str_replace( $re, $subst, $fp);

$put = file_put_contents("newfile3.txt", $result);

print_r($result);
echo 'testjn';

?>
```

Comment: the same with preg_replace?

Comment: i have some code for later require('simple_html_dom.php');

$table = array();

$html = file_get_html('newfile2.txt');
foreach($html->find('tr') as $row) {
     
    $calls = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext;
    $clast = $row->find('td',1)->plaintext;

Comment: though, its a huge html file, and collects too much. im just trying to trim the code up to use this script later

Comment: I've posted an answer below that should work for you, presuming that regex works. Take a look at that. I dont know what you are trying to parse so re-writing that regex or showing a parser example would be pretty hard.

Answer (score 1):

`fopen` returns a resource, not a string. You will need to use `fread` with that or `file_get_contents`.

Additionally `str_replace` doesn't work with regular expressions. You can use `preg_replace` for that.

```
$fp = file_get_contents('newfile2.txt');
$re = '/(\n*.*+)+\1<tr>\n.*<td bgcolor=\"#ffffcc\">/'; 
$subst = "<tr><td>"; 
$result = preg_replace( $re, $subst, $fp);
$put = file_put_contents("newfile3.txt", $result);
print_r($result);
echo 'testing';
```

You should look into using a parser for HTML/XML as well.  [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Here's how your regex currently works, https://regex101.com/r/gD0wP7/1. This question didn't seem to be about the regex though.